# Image histogram without ready function

Tags: matlab, histogram, python-3.3

I'm new to MATLAB.I want to extract a histogram of an image

```
clc
close all
clear all
picture=imread('space.jpg');
subplot(2,3,1);imshow(picture);
subplot(2,3,2);imhist(picture(:,:,1));title('red         ');
subplot(2,3,3);imhist(picture(:,:,    2));title('green ');
subplot(2,3,4);imhist(picture(:,:,3));title('blue ');
```

subplot(2,3,5);imhist(picture(1,1,1));title('white ');
    subplot(2,3,6);imhist(picture(:,:,:));title('black ');

I want to do this without imhist
Is it possible to do this ??

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: What's wrong with imhist ?